# How to remove default Android splash screen in react native

Tags: android, splash-screen, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

When my react-native app launche, it is showing white screen for few seconds. That white screen is actually default splash screen which android provides. Can anybody suggest **How to remove default android splash screen from react native app**
My AndroidManifest.xml looks like :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package=""
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
  <!-- android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> -->
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: then why white screen is coming at the launching of app for few seconds

Comment: Hey @Krishan Kumar , Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

That's not splash screen.thats just the window background.

If you want to disable it add the line below in your theme style.

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```